# Counting specific occurrences in DataFrame before other specific occurrences

Tags: python, dataframe, count

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({"event_time" :['2019-10-01 00:04:47 UTC','2019-10-01 00:04:49 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:04:51 UTC','2019-10-01 00:04:53 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:04:54 UTC','2019-10-01 00:04:56 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:04:58 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:01 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:03 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:03 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:06 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:07 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:10 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:10 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:13 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:13 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:14 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:15 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:16 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:17 UTC'], 
          "event_type": ['view', 'view', 'view', 'view','view','view','view','view',
                         'view','view','view','view','view','view','view','view',
                         'cart','view','view','view'], 
          "product_id": [5100816, 10800048, 15700176,17300555,12703015,2601543, 
                         1004966,1005115,1004284,4300285,26204088,13400134,19000265,
                         1002532,2700609,26400672,5100816,4300262,28101002,26300087],
           "category_id": [2053013553375346967,2053013554994348409,2053013559733912211,
                           2053013553853497655,2053013553559896355,2053013563970159485,
                           2053013555631882655,2053013555631882655,2053013555631882655,
                           2053013552385491165,2053013563693335403,2053013557066334713,
                           2053013557225718275,2053013555631882655,2053013563911439225,
                           2053013563651392361,2053013553375346967,2053013552385491165,
                           2053013564918072245,2053013563584283495],

            "user_id": [550121407, 539194858, 552373753, 520002471, 555448033, 513173999, 
                        523208885, 529755884, 513840435, 544648245, 515547943, 552795065, 
                        525734504, 551377651, 502372361, 555447748, 550121407, 523239174, 
                        537858238, 555448236],
})
```

```
                 event_time event_type  product_id          category_id    user_id
0   2019-10-01 00:04:47 UTC       view     5100816  2053013553375346967  550121407
1   2019-10-01 00:04:49 UTC       view    10800048  2053013554994348409  539194858
2   2019-10-01 00:04:51 UTC       view    15700176  2053013559733912211  552373753
3   2019-10-01 00:04:53 UTC       view    17300555  2053013553853497655  520002471
4   2019-10-01 00:04:54 UTC       view    12703015  2053013553559896355  555448033
5   2019-10-01 00:04:56 UTC       view     2601543  2053013563970159485  513173999
6   2019-10-01 00:04:58 UTC       view     1004966  2053013555631882655  523208885
7   2019-10-01 00:05:01 UTC       view     1005115  2053013555631882655  529755884
8   2019-10-01 00:05:03 UTC       view     1004284  2053013555631882655  513840435
9   2019-10-01 00:05:03 UTC       view     4300285  2053013552385491165  544648245
10  2019-10-01 00:05:06 UTC       view    26204088  2053013563693335403  515547943
11  2019-10-01 00:05:07 UTC       view    13400134  2053013557066334713  552795065
12  2019-10-01 00:05:10 UTC       view    19000265  2053013557225718275  525734504
13  2019-10-01 00:05:10 UTC       view     1002532  2053013555631882655  551377651
14  2019-10-01 00:05:13 UTC       view     2700609  2053013563911439225  502372361
15  2019-10-01 00:05:13 UTC       view    26400672  2053013563651392361  555447748
16  2019-10-01 00:05:14 UTC       cart     5100816  2053013553375346967  550121407
17  2019-10-01 00:05:15 UTC       view     4300262  2053013552385491165  523239174
18  2019-10-01 00:05:16 UTC       view    28101002  2053013564918072245  537858238
19  2019-10-01 00:05:17 UTC       view    26300087  2053013563584283495  555448236
```

I have the above DataFrame, that is in total about 14GB. What I need to do is count how many times a user has "viewed" a product before adding it to his cart. The problem is that many times the user will also "view" the product *after* having added it in the cart and even purchased it. This means that I cannot simply count them out. I tried this code:

```
products = list(data.loc[data["event_type"] == "cart"]["product_id"])
users = list(data.loc[data["event_type"] == "cart"]["user_id"])
idx_carting = list(data.loc[data["event_type"] == "cart"].index) 

views_count = []

for i in range(len(idx_carting)):
    sub_df = data.iloc[:idx_carting[i]]
    views_count.append(len(sub_df.loc[(sub_df["product_id"] == products[i]) 
                                  & (sub_df["user_id"]==users[i])]))
```

But it's way too heavy, I left it running for more than 2 hours, and it still hadn't completed the task. Anybody has a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Please don't post images. Provide a sample of your input dataframe as text with expected output.

Comment: I have provided a sample of the dataset!

Comment: Please post expected output for this input as well.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do that, I think what I have now shown isn't too clear. Should I attach the photo again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off selecting the elements of your data that you actually want to look at, group by those product and user ids, and then get the counts.  The following only counts views before first purchase.  So multiple purchases of the same item are not counted at all.

I added an extra line of data to show that the view events after first purchase are not counted.

```
import pandas as pd

sample = pd.DataFrame({"event_time" :['2019-10-01 00:04:47 UTC','2019-10-01 00:04:49 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:04:51 UTC','2019-10-01 00:04:53 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:04:54 UTC','2019-10-01 00:04:56 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:04:58 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:01 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:03 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:03 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:06 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:07 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:10 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:10 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:13 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:13 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:14 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:15 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:16 UTC','2019-10-01 00:05:17 UTC',
                                   '2019-10-01 00:05:19 UTC'],
          "event_type": ['view', 'view', 'view', 'view','view','view','view','view',
                         'view','view','view','view','view','view','view','view',
                         'cart','view','view','view', 'view'],
          "product_id": [5100816, 10800048, 15700176,17300555,12703015,2601543,
                         1004966,1005115,1004284,4300285,26204088,13400134,19000265,
                         1002532,2700609,26400672,5100816,4300262,28101002,26300087,
                         5100816],
          "user_id": [550121407, 539194858, 552373753, 520002471, 555448033, 513173999,
                        523208885, 529755884, 513840435, 544648245, 515547943, 552795065,
                        525734504, 551377651, 502372361, 555447748, 550121407, 523239174,
                        537858238, 555448236, 550121407]
```

Below we use two `groupby` object that share the same indexing.  The for loop is still slow, but will be faster than your current approach.

```
# get the list of product ids that are actually added to a cart
cart_products = sample.query('event_type=="cart"').product_id

# create groupings for each cart event for a user and product
# this is used to get the first cart event
gb_c = sample.query('event_type=="cart"').groupby(['user_id', 'product_id'])

# create a grouping of view events for each user and product where a 
# cart event also occurs in the data
gb_v = (
    sample[sample.product_id.isin(cart_products)]
        .query('event_type=="view"')
        .groupby(['user_id', 'product_id'])
)

# iterate over the groups, pull out the matching group, get the counts
counts = []
indices = []
for ix, g1 in gb_c:
    try:
        g2 = gb_v.get_group(ix)
    except KeyError:
        # handle rare case of an cart event with no view event
        continue
    counts.append(g2.loc[g2.event_time.lt(g1.event_time.iloc[0]), 'event_type'].count() )
    indices.append(ix)

# form a new data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'counts': counts}, 
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indices, names=['user_id', 'product_id'])
```

As an example, here is a data frame with 50 million rows, it takes less than 2 minutes on my laptop to finish.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = 50_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'event_type': np.random.choice(['view', 'cart'], size=s, p=(0.999, 0.001)),
    'product_id': np.random.randint(100000, 200000, size=s),
    'user_id': np.random.randint(100000, 150000, size=s)
    },
    index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=s, freq='mS', name='event_time')).reset_index()

cart_products = df.query('event_type=="cart"').product_id
gb_c = df.query('event_type=="cart"').groupby(['user_id', 'product_id'])
gb_v = (
    df[df.product_id.isin(cart_products)]
        .query('event_type=="view"')
        .groupby(['user_id', 'product_id'])
)

counts = []
indices = []
for ix, g1 in gb_c:
    try:
        g2 = gb_v.get_group(ix)
    except KeyError:
        continue
    counts.append(g2.loc[g2.event_time.lt(g1.event_time.iloc[0]), 'event_type'].count() )
    indices.append(ix)

pd.DataFrame({'counts': counts}, 
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indices, names=['user_id', 'product_id']))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! I like your method of creating two data frames and subtracting them based on the time! I don't understand one thing though, why when we take the difference we consider "iloc[0]"? Also it has been running for more than 25 minutes unfortunately, and it is still not done, but I guess it is inevitable with such a big dataset. Thank you again!

Comment: Using `.iloc[0]` selects the first occurrence of the 'cart' event in a given user/product grouping.  How many rows are in your data?

Comment: 109950743 rows are in my dataset!

Comment: You might be memory constrained.  The groupby operations can ramp up your memory usage